# Custom mailboxes in mac mail

Tags: email, folders

I got a new iMac last month and when setting up the Mac Mail I can no longer see my custom mailboxes (folders) that I have used to file my important emails for years!!!  I can see them in Yahoo.com (used by AT&T) and I can see them on my new MacBook Air and our phones/ipad!!!  How can I get them to appear in MacMail on my new iMac???
I do use time machine if that would enable me to bring them in…but don't know where to start.